# Why does global propogation of DNS records differ widely?

Tags: domain-name-system

I had been using DNSever for hosting zone records of my domains. Before that I was using the DNS servers of my domain registrars. I'd always noticed that global propogation of changed DNS records used to take between hours to half a day for propogating across the globe.

Today I installed bind9 on two VPSes, and setup zone records there after setting up nameserver entries at my registrars. I was rather surprised to find that whenever I made changes to the zone files, they propogated instantaneously across the globe except for locations in Indonesia and India.

How can there be a big difference in Global propogation depending on nameservers used? And how can the changes be instantaneously be propogated across the globe?

Comment: DNS records don't propagate. Cached records expire.

Comment: RE: servers picking up your changes "instantaneously", new records within a zone will always be picked up immediately unless they have been temporarily negative cached (i.e. someone was trying to access it before you created it). If you're *modifying* a record and need to do a time-sensitive cut-over, the only thing you can do is lower the TTL of the records in preparation for your change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you will never know how long it takes to 'propagate your records' [or more correctly - expire earlier cached entries]. there are some broken resolver dns out there that ignore [too low] ttl values and decide and override them with own bigger numbers.

Comment: And on the other end of the spectrum, some nameservers are configured to ignore TTLs over a configured maximum. Some of them purge their cache on an interval to reduce the volume of customer purge requests. And some servers are just plain broken.